# Allow moving out of a span at the end of a contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, editor, contenteditable

I'm trying to write a basic text editor using `contenteditable`. In this MCVE, it only has one function, which is that selected text is given a red highlight.<sup>†</sup>

The code I'm using is here:

```js
function createSpan() {
    let selection = document.getSelection();
    let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    let element = document.createElement("span");
    element.className = "inline-equation";
    range.surroundContents(element);

    let newRange = new Range();
    newRange.selectNodeContents(element);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(newRange);
}

$("button").click(createSpan)
```

```css
.inline-equation {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#editor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
Create Span
</button>
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
This is a contenteditable area.
</div>
```

I'm having trouble with the idea that the user may *move out* of the highlight area and continue typing in unformatted text. To experience this issue:

1. Run the Stack Snippet above
2. Select the text from somewhere in the middle til the end, then click *Create Span*
3. Type some new text at the end of the line

This new text has the red highlight too, even if you attempt to move out of the inserted `span` by pressing the right arrow key.

I'd still like to give the user the option to append new text which is formatted, but then also allow the user to navigate out of the `span` so that they may continue to type normal text.

In other words, the `span` should act as a completely separate editable object which may be moved into or out of. This includes the ability to move out of the `span` even if it's at the end of the document, so that the user can continue typing in non-formatted text.

The best example I am able to give of what I'd like is Microsoft Word's inline equations. Notice how, in the GIF below, the equation acts as a separate object, which I may navigate out of so that I can type normal text to the right of it. The is how I'd like my `span` to act.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/QEcDhHi.gifv]

I've tried replacing the `span` with a `div` with `inline-block` formatting to see if that affected the behaviour, but it didn't. How should I achieve the effect I'm looking for?

---

<sup>†</sup> In the actual use case, the 'highlight' actually denotes LaTeX-formatted mathematics which are rendered later. I'm writing what is essentially an editor for a proprietary markup language which supports inline LaTeX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you need something editable at end for this to work. There are lot of existing SO thread for the same. You can see below

[Why Is My Contenteditable Cursor Jumping to the End in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786048/why-is-my-contenteditable-cursor-jumping-to-the-end-in-chrome)

[contenteditable put caret outside inserted span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574522/contenteditable-put-caret-outside-inserted-span)

[contenteditable with nested span. Who has the focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897603/contenteditable-with-nested-span-who-has-the-focus)

[Focusing on nested contenteditable element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907091/focusing-on-nested-contenteditable-element)

Combining knowledge from above thread the simplest thing I could think of was adding below `keyup` handler

```
$("#editor").on('keyup',(e) => {
  var editor = $("#editor").get(0)
  var cn = editor.childNodes;

  if (cn[cn.length - 1].nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE)
  {
     empty = document.createTextNode( '\uFEFF' );
     editor.appendChild(empty);
  }

 if (cn[0].nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE)
  {
     empty = document.createTextNode( '\uFEFF' );
     editor.prepend(empty);
  }
})
```

Which makes sure there is one text node to step out of the div. You can do the same thing for the starting `div` if you want. Below is JSFiddle for the same

https://jsfiddle.net/4tcLr0qa/1/

[image: Edit content outside]

Comment: This works brilliantly! Strangely, it doesn't work in Firefox, but it works like a charm in Chrome, which is fine since I'm building a [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework) desktop app. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have to wait 8 hours to award the bounty so I'll do it then.

Comment: Btw, it works in in Firefox Developer 61 and not FF60. So some FF issue which will be fixed when FF61 is out.

Comment: Oh OK, even better then. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually seems to work in FF60 also now. But just a small lag or double right arrow needed there

Comment: Definitely doesn't work on my Firefox I'm afraid - FF 60.0.1 64-bit on Windows 10 build 1803. Still, it doesn't *need* to work in Firefox for my purposes. I'll see if it works on Firefox Dev.

Comment: Doesn't work on Firefox Dev 61.0b9 64-bit either for me. Could be Windows-related, but again, I'm not too concerned since I'll be using Chrome.