# Why does a contentEditable=true div doesn't accept textual input when focused via tabs?

Tags: html

to visualize my issue, I created the following html structure:

1. a father div
2. a children div

Both are with the same attributes: `contenteditable="true" tabindex="0"`.

**main.html:**

```
<html>
<div>
    <div contenteditable="true" tabindex="0">
        firstDivText
        <div contenteditable="true" tabindex="0">
            secondDivText
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Problem:

Navigating with tabs only (tabindex is 0 so its allowed), I can navigate to father and child with no problem.

When focus (given from tab) is on the **father** element, **I can immediatly start typing** to modify its context (contentEditable true).

But when focus is on the **child** element, **I must click it before I can modify the text!**

Question:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I fix it so that which element that is currently on focus will "receive" the key strokes?

Don't want to avoid using contentEditable nor to use jquery :S

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Focusing on nested contenteditable element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907091/focusing-on-nested-contenteditable-element)

Answer (score 0):

You better use inputs and avoid content editable you can style it to look the same.

```
.myInput{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border:none;
}
```

edit:
if you  really must you can fire click event on focus

```
$(".Mycontenteditable").focus(function(){
  $(this).click();
});
```

Comment: Hi,
I hate jQuery lol


I must use the contentEditable for other parts of the main project :S

any chance you know a different way that's not a work around?

Comment: not really although it works here https://codepen.io/TrentWalton/pen/avWVPr

Comment: Yeah, it's the nesting that messes it up. I'm looking for a short idomatic solution