# div contentEditable with non-contentEditable child can't remove

Tags: html, forms, contenteditable

I am very confused by contenteditable behavior, because sometimes is working and sometimes not. In this example is not working. When I remove all 
 then works

```css
.textarea{
  min-height: 100px;
}

.result-variable {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: dashed 1px #382781;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea" contenteditable="true">This i some data<br><span class="result-variable" contenteditable="false">Data 1 (can't remove)</span><br><span class="result-variable" contenteditable="false">Data 2 (cant remove)</span></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Focusing on nested contenteditable element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907091/focusing-on-nested-contenteditable-element)

Comment: no, because I have non-editable nested children and I just want to remove non-editable span by press backspace

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be with `<br>`. If you want a new line, you can use `white-space: pre`. But I advise to read about the problem with `pre`

```css
.textarea{
  min-height: 100px;
}

.result-variable {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: dashed 1px #382781;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea" contenteditable="true" style="white-space: pre">This i some data
<span class="result-variable" contenteditable="false">Data 1 (can't remove)</span>
<span class="result-variable" contenteditable="false">Data 2 (cant remove)</span>
</div>
```